# Users scrolls to the top and stays there for a period of time

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I want to use jQuery to

- detect if a user has scrolled to the top of the page and
- stays there for a period of time.

I've managed to get the first point working with the code below but don't have a clue about the second.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop()  == 0) {
   // do something
   }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps start a timer that goes off after a certain amount of time. If the user is still at the top of the page, execute order 66. You may also need to ensure that he does not move away in the meantime however.

Comment: basically, once the user gets to the top (inside your if) set a timeout, and if the user scrolls again you jsut clear the timer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you can do a setTimeout, and then clear the timeout if they scroll again. For example:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
    timer = setTimeout( doSomething, 2000 );
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
});

var doSomething = function(){
  alert('I just sat at the top for two seconds!');
};
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dXRhb/2/

​

Answer (score 1):

clear timeout if user scrolldown the page. other wise it will call function after 1000 ms(you can set it based on your requirement).

```
var c;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop()  == 0) {
    c = setTimeout(function(){
       // do stuff
     }, 1000);
 }
 else{
     clearTimeout(c);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTimer; // Global variable

$(window).scroll(function() 
{
  if($(window).scrollTop()==0) 
  {
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() { 
          /* what you want to happen goes here */
      }, 
      1000) // Time in milliseconds
  } 
  else 
  {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not account for the possibility the user leaves the top of the page during that interval.

Comment: @Jan, myTimer would only be global if you had not properly scoped your script. More than likely, this would be wrapped in a .ready method or some sort of constructor/function.

Comment: _"Accessible to the below function inbetween calls since it's a closure"_ just isn't as catchy...

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it without globals ?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
    $(this).data('scrollTimer', 
        setTimeout(function(){
            // do stuff
        }, 1000)
    );
 }
 else{
     clearTimeout($(this).data('scrollTimer'));
  }
});
```